# linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) using TesseractOCR

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have just installed the tesseraact OCR framework using the github instructions but i keep getting this error when building:

```
 Ld /Users/wayne.rumble/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Splitter-fkucamufumrohuhfuivayvewkjdc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TesseractOCRiOS/TesseractOCR.framework/TesseractOCR normal armv7
 cd /Users/wayne.rumble/Documents/iOS/Splitter/Pods
 export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
 export PATH="/Applications/Xcode_7.3.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode_7.3.1.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
 /Applications/Xcode_7.3.1.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch armv7 -dynamiclib -isysroot /Applications/Xcode_7.3.1.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.3.sdk -L/Users/wayne.rumble/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Splitter-fkucamufumrohuhfuivayvewkjdc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TesseractOCRiOS -L/Users/wayne.rumble/Documents/iOS/Splitter/Pods/TesseractOCRiOS/TesseractOCR/lib -F/Users/wayne.rumble/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Splitter-fkucamufumrohuhfuivayvewkjdc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TesseractOCRiOS -filelist /Users/wayne.rumble/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Splitter-fkucamufumrohuhfuivayvewkjdc/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/TesseractOCRiOS.build/Objects-normal/armv7/TesseractOCR.LinkFileList -install_name @rpath/TesseractOCR.framework/TesseractOCR -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fembed-bitcode-marker -weak_library /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib -llept -lstdc++ -ltesseract_all -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -single_module -compatibility_version 1 -current_version 1 -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/wayne.rumble/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Splitter-fkucamufumrohuhfuivayvewkjdc/Build/Intermediates/Pods.build/Debug-iphoneos/TesseractOCRiOS.build/Objects-normal/armv7/TesseractOCR_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/wayne.rumble/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Splitter-fkucamufumrohuhfuivayvewkjdc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TesseractOCRiOS/TesseractOCR.framework/TesseractOCR

ld: -weak_library and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES) cannot be used together
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm fairly new to using Swift and Xcode and am struggling to read this error code.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ld: -weak_library and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES) cannot be used together
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The linker is telling what the issue is here. I would try turning the Xcode setting `ENABLE_BITCODE=YES`. to `ENABLE_BITCODE=NO` and compile again and see if it removes that error. On the project settings view in Xcode you should be able to search for this setting and set to NO.

[image]

Comment: thanks for responding. i already had the Enable_BitCode set to no and double checked after the error. Any ideas?

Comment: i just fixed it, i changed the bitcode setting on the targert but not the project. now its not recognising any of the tesseract code ive put in. Thanks for you help. pushed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out i had changed the bitcode settings for the target but not the project!